# mootools load content with function

Tags: html, ajax, mootools

I am using mootools and i want to load in a div (named `response`) content.
The div content i pass in javascript with `$('response').set('html', content)` where content is variable. in the content variable i have some html *code with buttons* and want to create a event handle ( click ).

the content I load with a json request and pass to the element:

```
<div id="undo">
  <ul>
    <li> <button value="1">foo</button> </li>
    <li> <button value="2">bar</button> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

my javascript looks like

```
$('undo').addEvents({
    'click:relay(button)': function(ev, element){
         alert('a button clicked!');
    }
});
```

but I don't know why the event didn't work.

I think the problem is that `$('undo')` doesn't exist when the dom object is ready but i don't know how to fix this.

Comment: you could try to place the javascript in the html content that is added to the page.. (i doubt that will work, but it's worth the try)

Comment: delegate further up to an element that does exist. eg. `$('content').addEvent('click(relay(#undo button)', fn)`

Answer (score 0):

Delegate further up the dom tree to an element that is there at the time of domready block running. eg, if you have `<div id=content>... </div>` (or `response` if it's static)

```
document.id('content').addEvents({
    'click:relay(#undo button)': function(event, element){
        event.stop();
        console.log(element.get('value'));
    }
});
```

given that you inject your data there later on, this will work fine.